# Logic of reflective equilibrium

Tags: logic, epistemology, reason

[Reflective equilibrium](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reflective-equilibrium/) is the simple but compelling concept that a person reflects on conflicts between different beliefs that they hold, and revises their beliefs to reduce the conflicts, or to justify/unify some beliefs in terms of others.

Has anyone made a serious attempt at devising a logic that models this process? It seems that such a logic could be a closer match to human reasoning than any deductive logic. Conflict and unity could be measured as real numbers to optimize, so that we are not always dealing with black-and-white contradiction. We might also want some notion where we optimize only a small set of propositions at a time, rather than all of them at once, because that's what humans do.

In order for the process to converge towards a stable set of beliefs, there could be a need for real-valued propositional attitudes, where we do not simply hold P, we hold P with some level of resistance to changing it. Some beliefs that are foundational or encode sensory information might be immutable.

Comment: Seems to me that it's more like a proof technique than like a logic.

Comment: Re your "we are not always dealing with black-and-white contradiction", isn't this just Bayesian inductive logic of science? Also per typical Hegelian dialectic logic, the synthesis from thesis and antithesis may not arrive at a simple equilibrium...

Comment: Sounds a lot like the methods of deep learning networks.

Comment: @nwr most deep learning networks are aiming to solve for weight *parameters* given their solution based on their model is convergent (some cases could be rigorously proved, some may not). OP here seems concerning about beliefs of a set of (inconsistent or competing) *propositions*...

Comment: @DoubleKnot Bayesian inference is similar, but to actually perform exact Bayesian inference means you weigh all evidence from all sources in one step and come to an exact, correct probability. Humans can't do that. We look at a few ideas at a time, note problems with just those few ideas, and try to update our credences to improve things if we can see how. Perhaps some *approximation* to exact Bayesian inference could be like reflective equilibrium, but which approximation and how do you interpret the similarity?

Comment: [Making Reflective Equlibrium Precise: A Formal Model](https://journals.publishing.umich.edu/ergo/article/id/1152/), [Brun, Reconstructing Arguments: Formalization and Reflective Equilibrium](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Reconstructing-Arguments%3A-Formalization-and-Brun/8eb4f75d8f53be5d012e77c5f6fd617141b25a33).

Comment: @Conifold That's about formalizing an argument in regular FOL and using informal principles of reflective equilibrium, stated in English, to help do it.

Comment: There are things like defeasibility logic, logics of belief revision, and generally non-monotonic logics that structurally/conceptually resemble the thematics of reflective equilibrium. To some extent, the built-in requirement of overlapping consensus and public availability of relevant information makes overly formal spellings-out inadvisable, though Rawls, for example, does carry out the formalism in a very fine-grained way when the "scene calls for it," so to say.

Comment: @KristianBerry Defeasibility logic is *kind of* in the right direction, but it doesn't seem to capture the general concept of having a degree of conflict between ideas that is minimized. I don't know what you mean by "overlapping consensus and the public availability of relevant information." Reflective equilibrium happens in the mind of an individual, not in public.

Comment: @causative I'm going off Rawls' use, esp. in the final section of AToJ. Reflective equilibrium is coherentistic/Quinean, so an attempt at complete formalization would have to encompass subsets of balanced beliefs that can't be very determinable, so trying to formalize those subsets might not fit the "data set," so to say.